# Change div rows order in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to change row order in Bootstrap 3, using just css?

Example

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12">DIV 1</div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12">DIV 2</div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12">DIV 3</div></div>
```

I want to place DIV 1 under DIV 2 (on displaying page), but I don't want to change order of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this related question: [Bootstrap 3 changing div order on small screens only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20671303/584846)

The trick is to use `col-*-push-*` classes.

Here is another related solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069537/584846

It puts content into `table-header-group` and `table-footer-group`

Comment: It doesn't work on 12-col size, and i need only 12-col size columns. Also, your link is about columns, not rows

Comment: How about the second solution?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, thank you, but this doesn't suit. Seems to me, that the only  way is flexbox model, or js.

Comment: You asked for a solution using just css, though.