# Change div order with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i get the following behaviour?

md and lg

```
------------------------------------------------
|   img-3  |         table-6         | price-3 |
------------------------------------------------
```

sm

```
----------------------
|   img-6  | price-6 |
----------------------
|       table-12     |
----------------------
```

xs

```
-------------
|   img-12  |         
| table-12  | 
| price-12  |
-------------
```

Help is very appriciated!

So far i only managed to do md/lg and xs. But somehow i can not manage to get price and table switch as well as table have size 12 in sm size.

Here is what i di so far:
http://jsbin.com/gupanexasa/edit?html,output

I read: [Bootstrap 3 changing div order on small screens only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671303/bootstrap-3-changing-div-order-on-small-screens-only)
and [Bootstrap: change div order with pull-right, pull-left / 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929213/bootstrap-change-div-order-with-pull-right-pull-left-3-columns)

but could not reproduce it for sm size...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: change div order with pull-right, pull-left / 3 columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929213/bootstrap-change-div-order-with-pull-right-pull-left-3-columns)

Comment: If you ask me, I would never go through the trouble of having such complex class logic when this is so easy with `flex` and its `order` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution I find simpler :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 img">
     img
   </div>
   <div class="visible-sm col-sm-6 price">
     price
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mytable">
     table
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm col-xs-12 price">
     price
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the `col-xs-12` for? isn't this the normal behaviour?

Comment: I prefer make it explicit : it's more readable and usually I don't relay on default behaviours when I design a web page.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working demo, checkout.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <div class="row hidden-sm">  <!--hidden for only sm device-->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">img</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xs-12">table</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-xs-12">price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row visible-sm"> <!--Visible in sm device-->s
        <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">price</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">table</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to have each of them in `.row` (row class)

Here is what you need:

**md and lg** *(ps: just change `md` to `lg` for changing it to `lg`)*:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 img-3">
        // your stuff
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 table-6">
        // your stuff here
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 price-3">
        // your stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

**sm**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-6">
        // your stuff
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 table-6">
        // your stuff here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 table-12">
    // your stuff here
</div>
```

**xs**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 img-12">
        // your stuff
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 table-12">
        // your stuff here
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 price-12">
        // your stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the `.row` for xs

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pull/push only moves columns to left or right, and don't put cols on next or previous row when an overflow occurs. If it's not a problem to have the 'price' column twice, you can use hidden-* classes

[See Working demo](http://jsbin.com/saguzopaki/1/edit?html,output)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 img">
     img
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-xs price">
     price
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mytable">
     table
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm col-sm-6 price">
     price
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```