# Swaping divs with pull and push

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been reading a lot of documentation but I cannot succeed re-arranging some divs order. This is my code

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="slider">
                The slider
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <nav class="main-menu">
                The Menu
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want the menu to be over the slider (both with 16 column size) when screen enters sm. Is it possible?

Comment: `16-col` column size?  I thought `12` is max column size in `twitter-bootstrap`!!

Comment: There is a whole section dedicated to customize the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .row > div:first-child {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/aNRZRJ

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a Twitter Bootstrap oriented solution. Your code would destroy my entire layout

Comment: Have you looked at this already? [Bootstrap 3 changing div order on small screens only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671303/bootstrap-3-changing-div-order-on-small-screens-only)